# PHP Laravel 5 CLI terminate signal override

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Does PHP Laravel perform any cleanup when it get terminated by a [terminate signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC))?

For example the following code:

```php
class MyCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'get:help';
    protected $description = 'I need help';
    public function handle()
    {
        pcntl_async_signals(true);
        pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, [$this, "gracefullyShutdown"]);
        pcntl_signal(SIGINT, [$this, "gracefullyShutdown"]);

        // Do some procedure task here, no loop.
    }

    public function gracefullyShutdown()
    {
        // Do I need to do any clean up?
        //exit(0);
    }
}
```

Because the terminate signal function got override, the `handle()` continues  running.

If I want to call `exit(0)` in `gracefullyShutdown()` do I need to release memory or do anything else before `exit(0)`?

Or Can I call original terminate function like `super.terminate()` or something? (`super.terminate()` is psudo code)

I read about [How to gracefully stop a Laravel CLI command](https://smartapps.egeniq.com/how-to-gracefully-stop-a-laravel-cli-command-2bebb0b5884). But his approach is to have a `while(true)` loop, break out and execute remaining code. Where I want to stop/`return` anywhere in the `handle()`.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you’re trying to achive? At the moment it’s not clear why you wouldn’t just write `handle() { return; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about just flushing/destroying the session?